# Multiple Date Pickers - Using Value Changed

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

At the moment I'm adding methods to date pickers to make a change to a variable when the value is changed. Each picker has its own method.

Is there an easy way to combine the methods so I have a single methods which can check which picker was changed, or am I best of having each picker with its own method.

Currently I do

```
datePickerEnd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endPickerChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
datePickerStart.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startPickerChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
datePickerOrdered.addTarget(self, action: #selector(orderedPickerChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
datePickerReceived.addTarget(self, action: #selector(receivedPickerChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

@objc func endPickerChange () {
    finishedVisible = true
}

@objc func startPickerChange () {
    startedVisible = true
}

@objc func orderedPickerChange () {
    orderedVisible = true
}

@objc func receivedPickerChange () {
    receivedVisible = true
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker

Comment: change your functions to receive the sender as the first argument, eg. `@objc func endPickerChange (sender: UIDatePicker) {`, then you can just compare it inside the function to do the right thing `if sender == datePickerEnd {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your picker's value change events like this:

```
datePickerEnd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
datePickerStart.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
datePickerOrdered.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
datePickerReceived.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

Then define the common function like this:

```
@objc func pickerDidChange(_ picker: UIDatePicker) {
    switch picker {
        case datePickerEnd: print("datePickerEnd changed")
        case datePickerStart: print("datePickerStart changed")
        case datePickerOrdered: print("datePickerOrdered changed")
        case datePickerReceived: print("datePickerReceived changed")
        default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass *tag* for every date picker you are using. Try the code below -

```
func showDatePicker(forPickerName: String) {
    // Setup the UIDatePicker
    datePicker = UIDatePicker.init()
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    switch forPickerName{
    case "StartDate":
        datePicker.tag = 0
    case "EndDate":
        datePicker.tag = 1
    default:
        datePicker.tag = 2
    }

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
}
```

In you ***dateChanged*** you will get which picker value changed by using tag.

```
@objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker?) {
    print(sender?.tag)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if let date = sender?.date {
        self.view_DOB.tf_TextInput.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    switch sender?.tag {
    case 0:
        print("start date", dateFormatter.string(from: date))
    case 1:
        print("end date", dateFormatter.string(from: date))
    default:
        print("Other", dateFormatter.string(from: date))
    }
}
```

Call first function where you want date picker with related String -

```
  @IBAction func btnAction_PickedClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
             showDatePicker(forPickerName: "StartDate")
        case 1:
             showDatePicker(forPickerName: "EndDate")
        default:
             showDatePicker(forPickerName: "Other")
     }
 }
```

Copy and paste this code, It will work. Let me know if any issue. Happy coding :)

Comment: As far as I know developers should avoid using the TAG property nowadays.

Comment: @SalDev and what is the reason nowadays for not doing so?

Comment: I read it that Apple discourages us to use it. I don't know the exact source by now.